# How to dynamically generate radio buttons in the view with simple_form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I want to generate a list of radio buttons from an array of options in simple_form. Whatever option the user selects will get sent as the data for that particular field. The options array can be an a simple array or an array of hashes, it doesn't matter. Also I need some ability of making sure that the current value is selected. Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean `<%= simple_form_for ... %>`? Because `collection_radio_buttons` is a Rails helper, but if you're using Simple Form you may want to use its helpers.

Comment: You're right I was mixing the two up, I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare another instance variable in your controller and use it in the view?

Inside the controller action:

```
def whatever_action
  @user = # whatever
  @options = # however you get the options
end
```

Then in the form:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :options, @options, :first, :last %>
```

Comment: In this case is @options an array of hashes? What form does it need to take? Also, what is the significance of :first and :last and how do I indicate which is the currently selected option?

Comment: first/last is part of the [SF Helper API](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collection-radio-buttons) to determine which is the value and which is the label

Answer (score 0):

IMO this options array would be better located in a helper method but to each his own.

You could leverage OpenStruct in this case and it'll give you clean accessors so you don't have to ask... are my keys symbols or strings?

Then you can utilize it with simple_form's label_method / value_method options.

in Helper

```
# at top of helper module
require 'ostruct' 
module ApplicationHelper # (or whatever helper you want)
...

  # passed as an array of hashes, each hash composed of {id: __, value: "blah"}
  def dynamic_options(initial_values = [])
    initial_values.each do |hash_item|
      OpenStruct.new(hash_item)
    end
  end

...
end
```

then in view

```
f.collection_radio_buttons :options, collection: dynamic_options, :id, :value
```